# What does this SQL statement do in this Informix 4GL code?

Tags: informix, 4gl

I am missing something. Please can someone tell me how this works?

```
 let rpt.chgkey = null
  select cuschage.chgkey from cuschage where cuschage.cuschnum in
     (select shtwrd_no from crbookid where  
         crbookid.book_no = rpt.book_no and crbookid.line_no <= 3)

    let scratch = rpt.chgkey
    call make_charge_section(scratch) returning rpt.chgkey
 if rpt.chgkey is not null then
    print
    column 1, ESC, "(s0p12h0s3b4099T", ESC, "&a0.5R"
    print
    column 70, rpt.chgkey using "<<<<<<<<<"
end if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm...that SELECT statement is close to pointless.  You normally<sup>*</sup> execute a SELECT statement to get data into variables, but there is no INTO clause to put the returned value into.

Given that the SELECT does nothing with `rpt.chgkey`, the value in `scratch` is NULL.  The function `make_charge_section` is called with this value (NULL), and the result is saved in `rpt.chgkey`; the `CALL` is equivalent to:

```
LET rpt.chgkey = make_charge_section(scratch)
```

or you can do without the scratch variable and write:

```
LET rpt.chgkey = make_charge_section(rpt.chgkey)
```

(and you can do that with the `CALL` notation too).

Thereafter, you display some weird control sequence to your terminal — I'm not going to try and work out which terminal or what it does; are you sure you can't achieve the same effect with I4GL itself?  And then you display the new (non-null) value of `rpt.chgkey`.

So, the big unknowns here are 'why is the SELECT statement written without an INTO clause', and 'what does `make_charge_section()` do when given a NULL value as input'?

---

<sup>*</sup> The 'abnormal' uses of a SELECT without INTO would depend on you detecting errors in the SQL.  How that happens depends on what you've got the WHENEVER ERROR setting set to.